# Python: Why the function only extend the same data (the last loop data)?

Tags: python

a).Got the real data from global df(pardon dataframe).
b).Update the data to temporary dict(gd_tick_g1).
c).Extend list

Question: Why the function only extend the same data (the last loop data)?
Thanks.

```
global df, gl_price_vol

gd_tick_g1 =  {'AmountSum': [2116248500.0], 'Close': [50.1], 'Date': '2022/10/07', 'TickType': [2], 'Time': '09:11:41.107750', 'VolSum': [60000], 'Volume': [9]}
   
lens = len(df)
print(lens)

for i in range(lens-1, -1, -1):
    #(lens-1)~0, ex.lens=10, 9~0
            
    gl_price_vol.extend([2498])                 

    tick_type = df.iat[i,5] + df.iat[i,6]
    if tick_type == (-1):
        tick_type = 2

    gd_tick_g1['AmountSum'] = [i]            #test
    gd_tick_g1['Close'] = df.iat[i,3]        #d1
    gd_tick_g1['Date'] = '2022/10/07'
    gd_tick_g1['TickType'] = [tick_type]     #d2
    gd_tick_g1['Time'] = '09:11:41.107750'
    gd_tick_g1['VolSum'] = 60000
    gd_tick_g1['Volume'] = [df.iat[i,4]]     #d3
    #print(gd_tick_g1)                            #confime:update ok!
    gl_price_vol.extend({gd_tick_g1.values()})    #question: only extend the same data (the last loop data)
```

---

[2498,
dict_values([[0], 49.05, '2022/10/07', [2], '09:11:41.107750', 60000, [147]]),

2498,
dict_values([[0], 49.05, '2022/10/07', [2], '09:11:41.107750', 60000, [147]]),....

(all the same last loop data)
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because all the `dict_values` objects are referencing the same `dict` object, `gd_tick_g1`.

Why are you adding a `dict_values` object, instead of its elements? You can add its elements like this.

```
gl_price_vol.extend(gd_tick_g1.values())
```

If you really want to add a collection of that elements, do like this for example.

```
gl_price_vol.append(list(gd_tick_g1.values()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
(Why are you adding a dict_values object, instead of its elements? > I would like to create a full data format to simulate the real data-in. :) )

Comment: hi relent95,
Thank you for reminding me of dict referencing.
I try to move the for loop outside and call the function. The function could work well now. :)